# Libreoffice Writer - how to tell which image format I embedded?

Tags: libreoffice

I have a Libreoffice Writer document, into which I have added images (knowing my preferences, I have probably embedded, instead of linking them) (also the document file size suggests that all the image data is within).

In my documents folder, I have these images in several different encodings, with `.tiff`, `.png`, and `.jpg` extensions.

Now, a few weeks after I have created this document, I don't remember which image format I have used for the embedding. And I don't find a way on the Writer UI to identify that.

How could I tell?

(LibreOffice version: 6.4.6.2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An .odt file happens to also be simply a zipfile. You can open it in Archive Manager.

Look in the zipfile's "Pictures" folder (**NOT** the Pictures directory in your /home dir).

Here's an example of opening a .odt file in Archive Manager, and navigating to the Pictures subfolder. You can see that the image's original filename has been changed to a UUID-filename for the document's internal use, but the image type and size are clearly stated:

[image]

Comment: That UUID actually still appears as a filename: it has the extension at its end (but it got cut off by the ellipsis in your screenshot) :)

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have found a way: the image's right-click context menu has an option:

`Edit with External Tool`

When using this option, the "external tool", in my case the EOG image viewer app, will reveal the extension in its window's title bar.